# How to create 2 different log levels for stdout and file using logback.xml?

Tags: exception, logback

Below is my logback.xml 
I have added filter class to set different log levels but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    **<filter class ="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter"><level>WARN</level></filter>**
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    **<filter class ="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter"><level>INFO</level></filter>**

        <file>application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element or else
             the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
            <fileNamePattern>/srv/logs/application_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


</configuration>
```

And this is my java code where I am using logback configuration.

```
public class APIController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIController.class);

    ...
    private void handleException(Exception ex, String message) {
        logger.warn(message);

        if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
        ex.printstacktrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But still I see stacktrace on console. How should I keep 2 different log levels

Answer (score 0):

The `printstacktrace` method on exceptions just [directly prints the trace to the standard error output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--). If you want to log the exception, you need to use [a logging command](http://slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)), like

```
logger.info("An interesting exception happened", ex);
```